# Проблема с WebSocket и созданием localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

Создал локальный сервер, и хочу вывести сообщение в терминале vs code на стороне сервера. Для этого с помощью веб сокета его отправил. Но  вместо фразы которую я оправляю появляеться Buffer и моя зашифрованная фраза
вот код сервера

```
let server=require('ws').Server
let s=new server({port:'9001'})

s.on('connection',(ws)=>{
    ws.on('message',(mess)=>
    {
        console.log("This message",mess)
    })
})
```

А вот оправка текста с помощью веб сокет

```
  let mySocket=new WebSocket('ws://localhost:9001')
    console.log(mySocket)
    mySocket.onopen=()=>{
        console.log("Соединение установлено")
        setTimeout(()=>mySocket.send("123"),2000)
        
    }
```

В итоге получаю вот это каждый раз:

```
PS C:\Users\Евгений\Desktop\prim.wesocket\server> node .\chat-srv.js
This message <Buffer 48 65 6c 6c 6f 20 66 72 6f 6d 20 73 6f 63 6b 65 74>
```

Как мне выводить эту фразу но не зашифрованной?

Comment: что выводится если выводить как в примере `console.log('received: %s', data);`?

Comment: при использовании received все хорошо, спасибо. то есть без использования received не воспринимает текст?

Comment: тут суть не в received, а в [`%s`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Console#%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D1%81_%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA)

Comment: уже почитал. просто в примере в уроке все выводилось без этого символа. странно

Comment: что за пример???

Comment: пример                                                                                                                                       
       `s.on('connection', (ws) => {ws.on('message', (mess) => {console.log('Recieved:', mess)});`